# Is paperclip support rails3? how can i support upload pdf files only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

now i am trying to upload a pdf file to the server ,but i get nothing,when i try 
to get the url of the attached file,i got some missing.png file name.
Is there some where i can set to tell the paperclip that i just want to upload pdf files but
not pictures?
great thanks... here is my class settings

```
============================================model file
class RdBenefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reim_detail  
  has_attached_file :details
  validates_attachment_content_type :doc, :content_type => ['application/doc'] 
end

======================================schema
  create_table "rd_benefits", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "sequence"
    t.date     "reim_date"
    t.integer  "fee_time_span"
    t.integer  "people_count"
    t.decimal  "amount",               :precision => 10, :scale => 0
    t.integer  "reim_detail_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "details_file_name"
    t.string   "details_content_type"
    t.integer  "details_file_size"
    t.datetime "details_updated_at"
  end


==========================gemfile
gem "paperclip"


=========================view file
<%= form_for @doc_head,:remote=>true,:html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Comment: everything i config is as same as the docs, i just want pdf or doc files not pictures...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip works with Rails3.

If you want to limit your attachment just to PDF's, you should set up validation on your attachment like this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ['application/pdf']
```

Comment: i can't find any error messages and i got no uploaded file in my public directory

Comment: well my model which has attachment is a nested model with other,in the console it only shows [paperclip] saving attachments...but i got nothing

Answer (score 1):

use

```
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
```

gem if you are going to upload file via ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is :remote => true. It seems you cannot upload files over an XHR request.